# readXmlfile from java

Tags: java, java-io

Hello I've written small class in java to read in xml file as a string, not my question is following : how do I append string so it outputs only what is between Physical_Order_List_Array tags

here is a java class :

```
public static String getFileContent(String fileName)
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            String s;
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(s);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }

        finally {
            br.close();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

here is some of xml file its quite large :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
.....
.....
.....some content
....here is what I only need 
<Physical_Order_List_Array>
....now I need to get this portion of the code, append string to only output what is beetween these tags, including these tags as well
</Physical_Order_List_Array>
.....
.....
.....
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Can't you use existing XML parsers? Like SAX or DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't read the file as a string, read it using an XML parser and then use XPath to extract the nodes that you want. I've written articles on both [parsing](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=xml.parsing) and [xpath](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=xml.xpath) that will give you the code you need.

Also, define "quite large" -- is it a megabyte or a gigabyte? If the latter, then you'll need a SAX parser, which I don't describe. If the former, the DOM parser is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use XPath and use something like //Physical_Order_List_Array. You could parse the XML yourself (a fairly simple state machine would likely do the job in most cases).